# Live stream mp3 in Node

Tags: node.js, express, http, stream, mp3

So I'm trying to capture audio and then return a audio live stream in NodeJS. I want the response to be like this [example](http://wr11-ice.stream.khz.se/wr11_mp3). Notice how the browser opens up the file in a media player.

My current solution looks like this but it will render as "no video with supported format and mime type found"

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const AudioRecorder = require("node-audiorecorder");


app.get("/stream.wav", function (req, res) {
  res.set({
    "Content-Type": "audio/wav",
  });
  audioRecorder.start().stream().pipe(res);
});
```

The live stream works if I write the stream to a file first (code below) and open said file with VLC. It will continuously write to the file and VLC wont have any problem to follow along.

```
const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName, { encoding: "binary" });

// Start and write to the file.
//audioRecorder.start().stream().pipe(fileStream);
```

Ive been scratching my head all day but I'm stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the error by adding fluent-ffmpeg like this:

```
var stream = ffmpeg().input(audioRecorder.start().stream()).toFormat("mp3");
app.get("/stream.mp3", function (req, res) {
  res.type("mp3");
  stream.pipe(res);
});
```

There is a delay around 10s that ill have to work on.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the output audio format. Is is MP3 or WAV? Your answers suggest both. In the first case, MIME type should be *audio/mpeg*.

Also should replacing `res.set` by any of the following help?

`res.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType)`

`res.writeHead(statusCode,{'Content-Type': contentType})`.

`contentType` is "audio/wav", `statusCode` should be 200.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry about the confusion, I'll edit the post. But the format of the stream is wav.

I tried the headers you posted but the page will return a file to download and not a stream like in the example